# Why do mutate() and add_column() not accept the same basic arguments?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

Often I wish to add a new column at a specific index; mutate() does not have a simple implementation of this, while add_column() does via .before and .after arguments. I would expect the two functions to behave the same in simple settings, but they do not. Below is a MWE converting row index to a new variable. The R documentation does not make it clear: why do these two functions differ in their basic syntax?

```
dat <- as.tibble(matrix(rnorm(1e4), nrow=100))
dat1 <- dat %>% mutate(id=row_number()) # works as expected
dat2 <- dat %>% add_column(id=row_number()) # throws error
dat3 <- dat %>% add_column(id=1:nrow(dat), .before=1) # works, but harder to read
```

Comment: In the examples of `?row_number` it says `row_number can be used with single table verbs without specifying x (for data frames and databases that support windowing)`. `add_row` is not a dplyr verb, so would require a parameter for `row_number` (but careful; it returns a ranking). Simpler: `rowid_to_column`

Comment: Great tip on `rowid_to_column` -- will absolutely help with the posted use-case; though I remain curious about the broader question of the seeming disconnect between these two tidyverse functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you examine the code for these two functions, you will get some clues.

#### dplyr::mutate

```
function (.data, ...) 
{
    UseMethod("mutate")
}
<environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

#### tibble::add_column

```
function (.data, ..., .before = NULL, .after = NULL) 
{
    df <- tibble(...)
    if (ncol(df) == 0L) {
        return(.data)
    }
    if (nrow(df) != nrow(.data)) {
        if (nrow(df) == 1) {
            df <- df[rep(1L, nrow(.data)), ]
        }
        else {
            stopc("`.data` must have ", nrow(.data), pluralise_n(" row(s)", 
                nrow(.data)), ", not ", nrow(df))
        }
    }
    extra_vars <- intersect(names(df), names(.data))
    if (length(extra_vars) > 0) {
        stopc(pluralise_msg("Column(s) ", extra_vars), pluralise(" already exist[s]", 
            extra_vars))
    }
    pos <- pos_from_before_after_names(.before, .after, colnames(.data))
    end_pos <- ncol(.data) + seq_len(ncol(df))
    indexes_before <- rlang::seq2(1L, pos)
    indexes_after <- rlang::seq2(pos + 1L, ncol(.data))
    indexes <- c(indexes_before, end_pos, indexes_after)
    .data[end_pos] <- df
    .data[indexes]
}
<environment: namespace:tibble>
```

Firstly, you will note that they are from two different packages, albeit both part of the [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse).

Second, you will see that `mutate` uses a specified method whereas `add_column` is more of a convenience function written in base [r](/questions/tagged/r) with some [rlang](/questions/tagged/rlang) magic.

I'm not sure of the roadmap for either package, however, I'm sure you could propose an enhancement if there is not already one raised or fork the project and supply a pull request. It would be a useful addition.

#### Update

This has been raised in [tidyverse/dplyr](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2047) already and seems to be in the development pipeline, though not yet scheduled.

Comment: Any further updates or any other discussion happening on the roadmap of tibble functions and dplyr functions?